# Use or Initialize the value of local Variable on recursive JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, search

I would like to write a recursive function to parse nested JSON.

Here's how my JSON looks:

```
var data = {
  a: {
    x: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  },
  b: {
    y: ["ab"],
    z: ["abc"],
  },
  c: ["a1", "b1"]
};
```

Here's what I wrote:

```
var recurse = function(key, val) {
  window.mappedKey = window.mappedKey || '';
  if ($.type(val) === 'array') {
    if ($.inArray(search, val) >= 0) {
      window.mappedKey += key;
      alert(window.mappedKey);
    } else {
      window.mappedKey = '';
    }

  } else {
    window.mappedKey += key + '.';
    $.each(val, recurse);
  }
};

var search = 'ab';
$.each(data, recurse);
```

Here I used the global `window.mappedKey` to store previous key on the recursive. It worked fine, but is there any way to prevent this by using local variable within recursive function.

Comment: `data` is not JSON, it's simply a JS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can solve this problem.

1. As @MikeRobinson says, you can pass the value to recurse and store interally:

   ```
   for (var i in data) {
       if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          recurse(i, data[i], mappedKey);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Bind the `mappedKey` value to the function call

   ```
   $.each(data, recurse.bind(null, mappedKey);
   ```

In number 2, the mappedKey will be *prepended* to the arguments.

The final functions look (something like) as follows:
1.

```
    var recurse = function(key, val, mappedKey) {
        if ($.type(val) === 'array'){
            if($.inArray(search, val) >= 0){
                mappedKey += key;
            }
            else {
                mappedKey = '';
            }
        } else {
            mappedKey += key + '.';

            for (var i in val) {
                if (val.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    recurse(i, val[i], mappedKey);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var search = 'ab';
    for (var i in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            recurse(i, data[i], '');
        }
    }
```

2.

```
   var recurse = function(mappedKey, key, val) {
        if ($.type(val) === 'array'){
            if($.inArray(search, val) >= 0){
                mappedKey += key;
            }
            else {
                mappedKey = '';
            }
        } else {
            mappedKey += key + '.';
            $.each(val, recurse.bind(null, mappedKey));
        }
    };

    var search = 'ab';
    $.each(data, recurse.bind(null, ''));
```

Comment: Thank You @Paul 
It works for me and finally you saved me. :)

Comment: is there any way to return mapped key from this function?
so that I can write var finalKey = $.each(data, recurse.bind(null, ''));

Comment: dont hold me to this.. im just spitballing. but if you create a new variable `var ret = new String();` and pass that to the first recurse `$.each(data, recurse.bind(null, ret));` that string _might_ hold your final value. Its important that you use the string constructor `new String()` rather than a string literal `''` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't readily see the purpose of `mappedKey`, so bear with me.

Usually, when you want to pass information from one function instance to a recursion instance that it calls, you do so by passing the information as a parameter into the function.  Then, the function makes a local *copy* of that, makes modifications to the copy as needed, and then calls itself using the *copy*.  (In this way, it avoids altering the original value/list that was passed to *it*.)  When the function-instance disappears, so do all its local variables and therefore its copy.

Comment: Thanks.
Here I've to pass the mappedKey to the another method instead of alert it. Can we pass the extra parameter on  $.each(data, recurse); so that I can use this value in the recurse function

Comment: Notice that you're _modifying_ the `mappedKey` value that you've passed in, and passing _it_ to each recursion.  Instead of doing that, make a local copy.  Modify the local copy, and pass _that_ to the recursion.  The original value that was passed to the outermost instance ... is never touched.  The first instance copies it, then touches the _copy_, then passes the _copy_ to the next instance of itself.  Each instance never modifies the value that was passed-in to it.